# How to design List with sublist and sublist should be displayed on hover of parent list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

View New Records and & Old Rec should be opened when the pointer is hovered on View Rows

```html
<div>
     <li>Add Rows</li>
     <li>DeleteRows</li>
     <li>View Rows
       <ul>
         <li>View New Records</li>
         <li>View Old Records</li>
       </ul>
     </li>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

### **Pure CSS**

Use [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) to change the display of `.records` to block when you hover on the View Rows.

```css
.records {
  display: none;
}

.view:hover .records {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <li>Add Rows</li>
  <li>DeleteRows</li>
  <li class="view">View Rows
    <ul class="records">
      <li>View New Records</li>
      <li>View Old Records</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</div>
```

### **Pure Javascript**

And as always, there's multiple ways to do this. You can use pure javascript like below. This uses [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select the elements, [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to do something on [`mouseover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover) and [`mouseleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave). Obviously, this is much more complicated and harder than the previous method, but this leaves room for much more customization.

```js
var records = document.querySelectorAll(".records");
var view = document.querySelectorAll(".view")[0];

view.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  records.forEach(e => {
    e.style.display = "block";
  });
});

view.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  records.forEach(e => {
    e.style.display = "none";
  });
});
```

```css
.records {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <li>Add Rows</li>
  <li>DeleteRows</li>
  <li class="view">View Rows
    <ul class="records">
      <li>View New Records</li>
      <li>View Old Records</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</div>
```

### **jQuery**

And of course, theres a jQuery method. This uses [`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) to detect when you hover on the text, and then you use [`.show()`](https://api.jquery.com/show/) to show the li. Then you use [`.mouseout()`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) to detect when you go out of the text and [`.hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) to hide the text.

```js
$(".records").hide();

$(".view").hover(function() {
  $(".records").show();
});

$(".view").mouseout(function() {
  $(".records").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <li>Add Rows</li>
  <li>DeleteRows</li>
  <li class="view">View Rows
    <ul class="records">
      <li>View New Records</li>
      <li>View Old Records</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use at first ul visibility hidden and li: hover ul visibility: visible to displayed on hover of parent list.

```css
li:hover ul {
   visibility: visible;
} 

ul {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
     <li>Add Rows</li>
     <li>DeleteRows</li>
     <li>View Rows
       <ul>
         <li>View New Records</li>
         <li>View Old Records</li>
       </ul>
     </li>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[**see js fiddle example here**](https://jsfiddle.net/razibmahmud50/4p2y3u8v/19/)

```css
ul {
  background: #333;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}

ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  display: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

ul ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
       <li>Add Rows</li>
       <li>DeleteRows</li>
       <li>View Rows
         <ul>
           <li>View New Records</li>
           <li>View Old Records</li>
         </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```